# 504-gateway time out error happens after 60 seconds of run time

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to run a process in my application that takes at least 30 minutes but I get 504-gateway time out error within 60 seconds. The application is hosted in EC2 instance of AWS and I am a developer.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Holding connection for many minutes is not recommended. It is a wastage of both caller and called resources.

You can send request to server and drop it then, poll the server for completion.

Solution should have following aspects:

1. Activate API to call from outsider for job
2. outsider sends API request to start the job
3. API generates an unique token and send it as the response while starting the process in a different thread.
4. Outsider polls the API with the token for the completion
5. Server stores result of the job along with the token.
6. Result can be responded to immediate poll.

Comment: This is not the question of the OP. Let's say that the request takes 61 seconds, it will be close too with a timeout error. He's asking where to look or where is configured that 60 seconds timeout. You are giving hints to solve a business logic problem, not a technical question of the OP problem.